# ¿Es posible Vincular Heroku con Akky (proveedor de DNS)?

Tags: heroku, dns

Estoy desplegando una app en Heroku, tengo un dominio registrado en Akky, pero el redireccionamiento no se lleva acabo.

Hasta donde entiendo Heroku proporciona el dominio a travez de CNAME.

La pregunta es ¿Alguien a podido redireccionar un Dominio de Akky a Heroku? De no ser posible, ¿Que opcion tendria?

Estoy pensando cambiar de proveedor de DNS pero quiero descartar todas las opciones primero.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad Demon. Por favor edita tu pregunta agregando el código que hasta ahora escribiste y especificando en qué parte y qué error devuelve, así como el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví.

Se tiene que contratar un servicio adicional de Dominios Personalizados. Contratamos el servicio de Dominios Personalizados en el dominio deseado.

Dentro de Dominios Personalizados, dentro del dominio deseado, En la parte inferior aparece "Agregar registro" que mostrará otra ventana. En esta seleccionamos CNAME, ponemos el registro que nos dio Heroku.